# Multiprocessing/Multithredding 3 nested loops in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, nested-loops

I have a snippet of the following code:

```
for x in xrange(100,14000):
    for y in xrange(0,3000):
        for z in xrange(0,700):
            operationg_tag = "%s-%s-%s" % (x,y,z)
            operation_code = ....

            and more bunch of code is running here on the tag generated above
```

I'm running this code in a quick good hardware, but the nature of these loops are slow because there's not running in Multiprocessing/Multithredding

It takes around 0.4 seconds to execute the needed code on every tag.

How can I implement Multiprocessing/Multithredding in these nested loops to make it run faster? which of the loops should I target?

Comment: #1, multithreading won't help here at all. It has to be multiprocesing. #2, it depends on your hardware, number of cores, bus latencies, etc.

Comment: Try a few different approaches and see what works. this is not a free coding service.

Comment: Whether multiprocessing is or isn't a good idea (or even whether it is better that multithreading) definitely depends on the *bunch of code which is running here*. What kind of code is running there? Is it the kind of code which locks GIL? Is it code which takes a lot of data as input and/or returns a lot of data as output?

Comment: @zvone Majority of it is reading a file (~100KB) and parsing data from it.  it's like 8 lines long for that function.

Comment: @rootameen File access does not lock GIL. Parsing (in python) does. What do you do with the parsed data? Do you need to return a lot of data to the calling function? If not (e.g. if you are just saving results to another file), it seems perfectly logical to split that into separate processes, which just take x, y, z as input and return nothing as output. The question of input/output is important because the major problem with multiprocessing is communication between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the first loop in like 3 process,

```
    def func(start, final):
         for x in xrange(start, final):
              for y in xrange(0,3000):
                   for z in xrange(0,700):
        operationg_tag = "%s-%s-%s" % (x,y,z)
        operation_code = ....
    def main():
        total = 14000
        div_total = int(14000 / 3)
        rest_div_total = 14000%3
        t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = func,name = "", args=(100, div_total)
        t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = func,name = "", args=(div_total, div_total*2)
        t3 = multiprocessing.Process(target = func,name = "", args=(div_total*2, div_total*3 + rest_div_total + 1)
        list_threads = [t1,t2,t3]
        for i in list_threads:
           i.start()
        for i in list_threads:
           i.join()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

You can create more processes if you'd like, but 3 It's good enouth.

Comment: Thanks @Joao, I've applied slight modification to your main by adding more threads and it is giving me the desired output.